# How to position the dropdown menu of React Native Picker

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to display a dropdown menu in a React Native android app. I used React Native Picker for the purpose, and it seems very limited in styling and positioning the dropdown menu. I cannot get the menu to pop up below the carret (the down arrow button) position.

I tried setting the margin with hope to push the menu down, to no avail.

```
              <Picker
                // selectedValue={stateValue}
                style={{
                  height: 36,
                  width: 261,
                }}
                onValueChange={itemValue => {
                  console.log('item value ', itemValue);
                }}
              >
                <Picker.Item key={-1} label={'Search By...'} value="first" />
                {this.searchCategory.map((item, index) => (
                  <Picker.Item key={index} label={item} value={item} />
                ))}
              </Picker>
            </View>
```

The menu always covers the Picker component. I want it to appear below the Picker.

Actual behavior:

[image: Actual behavior]

Expected behavior:
[image]

Comment: This is the default Spinner behavior of Android. You cannot change it. Set the mode property on React Native Picker to "dialog" if you want to change the behaviour. If you want to have more control, use a custom Picker like: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-custom-picker

Comment: So there is no way to change this behavior? The package you mentioned is quite unpopular, so I kind of hesitate to try it.

Comment: To my knowledge, no you cannot change this behaviour. I honestly think dropdown should never show like the way you want it on smartphone screen. Because the screen size is limited. That is why they have the mode property.

Comment: The app is meant to be displayed on a POS device, hence the design. But I understand your point now. I'll look around for a different package / solution, as RN Picker is so limited in terms of styling.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some research, this is an Android limitation and it seems there's little we can do with React Native Picker. Some custom packages may give us more control such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-picker-select, or https://github.com/sohobloo/react-native-modal-dropdown.